# How do I create a Dynamic Skeleton loading component for a ReactJS application?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use react-loading-skeleton package like below

```html
import React from 'react';
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton';

function SkeletonComponent() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'inline-block',
        width: '300px',
        height: '180px',
        borderRadius: '8px',
        background: 'antiquewhite',
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: '8px',
      }}
    >
      <Skeleton height={30} width={20} circle={true} />
      <h2>
        <Skeleton type='circle' />
      </h2>
      <h3>
        <Skeleton />
      </h3>
      <h4>
        <Skeleton />
      </h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SkeletonComponent;
```

How should I use skeleton component for whole page instead of each HTML elements?

Answer (score 0):

In the [react-loading-skeleton](https://github.com/dvtng/react-loading-skeleton#readme) page

```
function BlogPost(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.title || <Skeleton />}</h1>
            {props.body || <Skeleton count={10} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Try this